# Adding Qt in QNX Momentics IDE

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I have experience with blackberry java environment.But I need to know about QNX based IDE for development of Blackberry 10.I successfully installed all setup.  And also run some small example.
I need to develop cover-flow with Blackberry10. Some of my friends told me that it can be done with Qt.But I get error when importing Qt. What is the problem . And how can I develop cover-flow with QNX Momentics

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QNX). It describes how to set up and build Qt for BlackBerry. I am not however sure if that will work with QNX Momentics.
Have a look at [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Integrating-Qt-with-QNX-Momentics-IDE/td-p/1557137) as well. I am not sure if you will be able to get full Qt QML support on Momentics IDE. You could maybe try using QtCreator.